# Linker Error Caused by Same Header Inclusion

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, clang, linker-errors

I am currently developing an application in Xcode for Mac. I am usually pretty decent at finding out how to solve problems when they arrive, but one error always gets me. When I include the same header in two separate classes I get the duplicate symbol error. My code looks like this:

**Utilities.h**

```
#ifndef __UTILITIES_H
#define __UTILITIES_H

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

#import "Path.h"
#import "Matrix.h"
#import "Shader.h"
#import "Texture.h"

#endif
```

**BlaineEntity.h**

```
#import "Utilities.h"

@interface BlaineEntity : NSObject
{
    GLuint blaineID[3];
    GLfloat modelMat[16], rotMat[16], transMat[16];
    GLuint blaineVID[1];
    GLuint textureID;
    GLint uniform_mytexture;

    Matrix *matrix;
    Texture *tex;
}

- (void)render;
- (void)update;
- (void)setup;
- (void)setLocation:(GLfloat)x y:(GLfloat)y z:(GLfloat)z Rotx:(GLfloat)rx Roty:(GLfloat)ry Rotz:(GLfloat)rz;
- (void)translate:(GLfloat)forward lr:(GLfloat)lr ud:(GLfloat)ud;

@end
```

**TempEntity.h**

```
#import "Utilities.h"

@interface TempEntity : NSObject
{
    GLuint tempID[3];
    GLfloat modelMat[16], rotMat[16], transMat[16];
    GLuint tempVID[1];
    GLuint texID;
    GLint uniform;

    Matrix *matrix;
    Texture *tex;
}

- (void)Render;
- (void)Update;
- (void)Setup;
- (void)SetLocation:(GLfloat)x y:(GLfloat)y z:(GLfloat)z Rotx:(GLfloat)rx Roty:(GLfloat)ry Rotz:(GLfloat)rz;
- (void)Translate:(GLfloat)forward lr:(GLfloat)lr ud:(GLfloat)ud;

@end
```

What can I do to avoid the linker error...

**EDIT**
Here is the linker error

```
duplicate symbol _started in:
/Users/sonardev/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Blaine's_Adventures:_The_Lost_Mark-eyovjgtlqhbbcoeukwivyitbhqly/Build/Intermediates/Blaine's Adventures: The Lost Mark.build/Debug/Blaine's Adventures: The Lost Mark.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/TempEntity.o
/Users/sonardev/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Blaine's_Adventures:_The_Lost_Mark-eyovjgtlqhbbcoeukwivyitbhqly/Build/Intermediates/Blaine's Adventures: The Lost Mark.build/Debug/Blaine's Adventures: The Lost Mark.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/BlaineEntity.o
ld: 1 duplicate symbol for architecture x86_64
```

Comment: Post the linker error.

Comment: @Zaph Ok, I edited it to add the linker error

Comment: Could you also post the definition for `started` or `_started`, probably in one of the `.h` files imported in `Utilities.h`?

Comment: There is one duplicate symbol: `_started`. it could be a method named `started`. Search for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of headers included into `Utilities.h` contains symbol `_started` (probably it is function). So `_started` indirectly included into 2 files with classes implementations, that causes linker error. Check all headers inside project included to `Utilities.h`.

Comment: Could be in one of the four headers imported by Utilities.h.

Comment: You were right, and not right. It did have something to do with a symbol named started. But for whatever reason, it was a BOOL value that I hadn't removed yet that was sitting in my code set to false. Do you know why it would do that?

Comment: Show the code?? Also when you get error messages really spend the time to try and understand them, Sure linker error messages seem the worse but they are not that hard to get clues from.

Comment: Like it was literally just a global BOOL variable outside the functions. It was like BOOL started = false; and then a function afterwards. I put it global just for the sake of a simple test of something I was working on (Looking back I really don't know why it was necessary to be there)